# Classification with package "deepnet" in R

Tags: r, deep-learning

I am trying to use package `deepnet` in R to classify. I tried:

```
Var1 <- c(rnorm(50, 1, 0.5), rnorm(50, -0.6, 0.2))
Var2 <- c(rnorm(50, -0.8, 0.2), rnorm(50, 2, 1))
x <- matrix(c(Var1, Var2), nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
y <- c(rep(1, 50), rep(0, 50))
y = as.factor (y)
y = data.matrix (y)
```

then I tried to train

```
dnn <- dbn.dnn.train(x, y, hidden = c(5, 5))
```

but I have a problem

```
begin to train dbn ......
training layer 1 rbm ...
training layer 2 rbm ...
dbn has been trained.
begin to train deep nn ......
Error in batch_y - nn$post[[i]] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What is the correct way to classify the data with `deepnet` package?

Comment: Why do you apply `as.factor` and then `data.matrix` to `y`? Remove those two lines and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

use `y=as.numeric(y)` after converting to matrix form. Use `as.matrix` for `x`. Check `x` & `y` is conformable for multiplication. It will work for `dbn.train`, but fails while `rbm.train` is evoked.
You can use stacked encoder dnn. It will work smoothly. But classification results should be improved further. i don't know how to improve the confusion matrix values. Any one can help